# Split variable with html tags in multiple variables

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, text, split

I have a jquery variable with text seperated by a html break (in example repesented by |): [this is sentence 1 | this is sentence 2 | this is sentence 3].

I want this text split in 3 variables on the [break] tag to assign them to 3 seperate fields.

How do I do this? I tried with the split function but no luck (html tag as seperator does not work)

Comment: can you provide the variable with html tags

Comment: 8u30-12u30 | 13u-16u30<br \>of op afspraak<br \>Tijdens weekends gesloten

Comment: if there is only `<br />` tag then you can simply use `str.split("<br />");`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making this variable an array or an object, the current variable looks like a string of text, unless there are definite separators between the items you want, it will be really hard to split them.

Once you have an array or object with 3 items, you can loop through, find by index etc.